# Debugging the script

Tags: audio, processing, visualization

I am trying out processing and was fiddling a bit with music/audio visualization.

What I did was to create spheres with a random colour, which worked perfectly.

What I then tried to do is add random triangles and squares, randomly on the screen.

I am getting an error and I can't seem to find the root of the error.

This is my code:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
AudioPlayer song;
Minim minim;

float left ;
float right ;

int width = 800;
int height = 640;

PShape square;
PShape triangle;
PShape hexagon;
PShape star;


void setup ()
{
  size (width,height,P3D)  ;
  smooth();
  background (10,10,10) ;
  frameRate(20) ;
  minim = new Minim(this);
  song = minim.loadFile("song.mp3");

  square = createShape(BOX, random(height/8));
  triangle = createShape(TRIANGLE, random(height/8), random(width/8));

}

void draw ()
{
//  background (30,ri) ;
  noStroke() ;

  for  (int i = 0; i < 255 ; i++)
  {
    right = song.right.get(i)*100 ;
    left = song.left.get(i)*100 ;
  }

    background(10,10,10);
    fill(random(255), random(255),random(255), random(255)) ; //NOIR
    ellipse(width/2, height/2, random(800), random(640)) ;
    stroke(random(255),random(255),random(255),random(255)) ;
    noFill() ;
    ellipse(width/2, height/2, random(800), random(640)) ; 

    for (int j =0; j < 255; j++)
    {
       shape(square, random(800), random(640)); 
       shape(triangle, random(800), random(640));

    }

}
```

This is the error:

```
[java.lang.NullPointerException]

Wrong number of parameters
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PGraphics.shape(PGraphics.java:3789)
    at processing.core.PApplet.shape(PApplet.java:12869)
    at SoundVisuals.draw(SoundVisuals.java:70)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:193)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:541)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.paint(GLCanvas.java:595)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
    at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103)
    at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:206)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:172)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:191)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:541)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL.requestDraw(PJOGL.java:688)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1651)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PGraphics.shape(PGraphics.java:3789)
    at processing.core.PApplet.shape(PApplet.java:12869)
    at SoundVisuals.draw(SoundVisuals.java:70)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Processing reference here: https://www.processing.org/reference/

Then pay closer attention to the createShape() function reference: https://www.processing.org/reference/createShape_.html

From that:

> The basic way to use the function defines new primitive shapes. One of the following parameters are used as the first parameter: ELLIPSE, RECT, ARC, TRIANGLE, SPHERE, BOX, QUAD, or LINE. The parameters for each of these different shapes are the same as their corresponding functions: ellipse(), rect(), arc(), triangle(), sphere(), box(), and line().

Now take a look at the triangle() function reference: https://www.processing.org/reference/triangle_.html

> A triangle is a plane created by connecting three points. The first two arguments specify the first point, the middle two arguments specify the second point, and the last two arguments specify the third point.

That tells us that the triangle() function requires 6 arguments. But you're only passing in 2 arguments when you call createShape(Triangle).